# Matching 2 different files by first column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

So I have 2 different files.

file1.txt is:

```
abcdefjeiireiiioe:data:otherdata  
rijirjeiwrieeoooe:datamore:otherdatamore
```

file2.txt is:

```
abcdefjeiireiiioe:data:otherotherdata  
rijirjeiwrieeoooe:datamore:otherotherdatamore      
*other random lines which do not occur in file1.txt also and are not needed
```

How can I print them on the same line so that they are like:

```
abcdefjeiireiiioe:data:otherdata:data:otherotherdata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want the second line merged as well. You can use `join`:

```
join -t : file1 file2
```

This parses `file1` and `file2` using `:` as separator, and merges lines whose first field matches. By default lines which don't match are ignored and don't appear in the output.

The input files need to be sorted on the join field; if they're not, you can pre-process them:

```
join -t : <(sort -k 1,1 -t : file1) <(sort -k 1,1 -t : file2)
```

or you can try ignoring the sort check:

```
join -t : --nocheck-order file1 file2
```